# how to process a select on a multiple row returning select

Tags: sql

I have two tables `user_roles` which will have rid and uid which is user id and role id. I want to extract the uid from the role id and enter it into users tables to get a the users with rid 6. How do I do this in sql?(I am using phpmyadmin to extract data from a project I am migrating).This is what I tried.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid =(select uid from `users_roles` where rid= 6 )
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected result based on that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid in (select uid from `users_roles` where rid= 6 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN for this:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
JOIN users_roles ur
    ON u.uid=ur.uid
WHERE ur.rid=6
```